# CSS: How to put form input fields and button next to each other in the same line?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the following:

[image]

but I cannot get the background right. I've created this fiddle so you see what I've done. http://jsfiddle.net/dya9xh1e/

```
field { 
  font-family:arial, sans-serif; 
  border-color: #d9d9d9; 
  border-top:solid 1px #c0c0c0; 
}

input.field{
  width:140px;
}

.fieldwrapper{
  background-color:#CCC;
  width:500px;
  height:180px;
}
```

Could someone please advise on this?

Comment: Is that ok for you? http://jsfiddle.net/dya9xh1e/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dya9xh1e/3/
I hope this works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/rp1m13kk/

here you have something similar to the pic

```css
input { font-family:arial, sans-serif; border-color: #d9d9d9; border-top:solid 1px #c0c0c0; background-color:#CCC; display: inline;} 
    input.field{width:140px;}

    .fieldwrapper{
     background-color:#FFF;
     width:1000px;
     height:80px;
        border: 2px solid #CCC
    }

    #findbutton{background-color:red;}
```

You have several mistakes, for example in the firstline of your CSS, you need to add a `.` to reference the class. In my solution was change by the `input` selector.

Then I added the `display:inline-block` property to make components inline. But you need to change the container size, in order to fit the total input width, that's why I put `1000px`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make a wrapper block to control the elements inside each divisions and then push to left using float left; Otherwise just use float:left for both input and label.

```css
field { font-family:arial, sans-serif; border-color: #d9d9d9; border-top:solid 1px #c0c0c0; } 
input.field{width:140px;}

.fieldwrapper{
 background-color:#CCC;
 width:500px;
 height:180px;
}
.left{
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="popForm">

<div align="center" class="fieldwrapper"> 

<form id="myform" action="" method="post">

<input type="hidden" id="top" name="top"/>
<input type="hidden" id="left" name="left" />

    <div class= "left">
        <label for="name">NAME</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name" />
    </div>
    
<div class= "left">
    <label for="company">COMPANY</label>
    <input type="text" style="width:140px;" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Your name"  />
</div>


<input type="submit" id="findbutton" class="left" value="PLACE FLAG" /> 

</form>

</div> 
</div>
```